# Problems with .scroll function in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to get a div to go from 100% opacity to 0% opacity on scroll.

I made this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wSkmL/853/) and it works great in a web browser, just as I'd hope. It works in mobile browsers too, but with one horrible downside.

```
var divs = $('.cover_image');
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  divs.css({
    'opacity': (1 - st / 40)
  });
});
```

(What is happening in the fiddle is the top div is going to opacity:0 as you scroll, revealing another div below it with the same background-image, but blurred. Creating the impression the same image is blurring the more you scroll)

In a web browser as you scroll the div drops in opacity progressively with a fade like affect which is great.

**However in a mobile browser the change of opacity doesn't take effect until you release your finger from the the screen.** So there is no progressive change of opacity. It only makes the changes visually as you release your finger from the screen, not as you scroll.

Is there a solution for this? I have tried adding in scrolling touch to my css, but it doesn't make a difference.

```
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrolling distance on mobile works very different from desktop. Even if you detect each step in the touch event, this is only half the truth. When the user releases, the site will continue to scroll for a bit while deaccelerating. This is called momentum scroll and will in most cases not be picked up by the touch event.

There are to my knowledge no perfect solution to this, since different devices handle scroll and touch very differently. There are however a few options you could look into.

## Scrolling libraries

There are libraries to help you solve this problem. For instance one called [scrollability](https://github.com/joehewitt/scrollability) that emulates scrolling to work more consistently.

> Scrollability adds a good imitation of iOS native scrolling to your
>   mobile web apps.
>
> Scrollability is a single script, it's small, and it has no external
>   dependencies. Drop it into your page, add a few CSS classes to
>   scrollable elements, and scroll away.

## Ignore the scroll completely

Don't look at the touch or scroll events. Instead use `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` with desired frequency that reports the pages current position (`document.documentElement.scrollTop`) at all time. Base your animation on this value instead of scroll or touch events. You might want to limit this to touch devices since it's not needed for desktop.

## Write your own scroll functionality

Disable scrolling and make your own, without for instance momentum scroll, that is suited for your needs. Note that the `scroll` event is usually disabled on desktop if you disable scroll, but `mousewheel` works. I have been down this path and I would not recommend it. Instead you should probably go with the library approach at the top.